# Call function from binding returning error

Tags: swift, swiftui

On the line:

```
ForEach($trip.myFunction(), id: \.id) { $stop in
```

I get the error:

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<() -> [Binding]>'

Here is what the `Trip` model looks like:

```
struct Trip: Codable, Identifiable {
    let stops: [TripStop]?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case stops = "stops"
    }
    
    func myFunction() -> [TripStop] {
        if let stops = stops {
            return stops.filter({ $0.date == nil })
        }
        return []
    }
}
```

Am I not able to call `myFunction()` from a binding? How would I address this?

Comment: Binding is by definition a two way connection a function isn’t two way, you have to rethink your logic

Comment: @loremipsum Any ideas on best practices for alternatives?

Comment: Don't use a function, it's hard to tell what your true intentions are but generally anytime you "filter" in the body it is a bad practice. The body is for displaying things not doing work. It is possible to do something like this with generics but I would expect a ton of little bugs.

Comment: I'm trying to get a list of all `stops` where the `date` object is nil.

Comment: Just remove the `$`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass an array of `TripStop` to `ForEach`, and also remove `$` here, it's for data binding. You might want to take a look at this tutorial for [data with bindings](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/app-dev-training/passing-data-with-bindings).

```swift
struct TripView: View {
    ...
    var validTripStops: [TripStop] {
        trip.stops?.filter { $0.date == nil } ?? []
    }
     
    var body: some View {
        //You can remove id keyPath here 
        //if TripStop model conforms to Identifiable
        ForEach(validTripStops) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to his original functions logic the logic is:
`stops.filter({ $0.date == nil })`

You have checked `date != nil`, recheck and update.

Comment: Oops thanks for pointing out this mistake @MahiAlJawad

Comment: @son Am I able to put `validTripStops` inside my `Trip` codable model?

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's depend on you. I often leave the DTO standalone, because I can automatically generate it.