# Binding value updating, but not being reflected in view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a view that looks like this:

```
struct StopDetailsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var tripManager: TripManager
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    @Binding var stop: TripStop

    @State private var showDatePicker = false
    @State private var selectedDate: Date? = nil
    
    init(stop: Binding<TripStop>) {
        self._stop = stop
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Button(action: {
                        showDatePicker.toggle()
                    }) {
                        HStack(alignment: .center) {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                if (stop.date != nil) {
                                    Text(stop.date?.formatDate(fromFormat: "YYYY-MM-dd", toFormat: "EEEE") ?? "")
                                        .font(.custom("Inter-Regular", size: 14))
                                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                }
                                
                                Text(stop.date?.formatDate(fromFormat: "YYYY-MM-dd", toFormat: "MMMM dd, YYYY") ?? "No date set")
                                    .font(.custom("Inter-Medium", size: 16))
                                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showDatePicker) {
                CustomDatePicker(
                    components: [.date],
                    showDatePicker: $showDatePicker,
                    savedDate: $selectedDate,
                    selectedDate: selectedDate ?? Date()
                )
            }
            .onChange(of: selectedDate) {
                updateDate()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateDate() {
        tripManager.updateTripStopDate(tripId: stop.tripId, tripStopId: stop.id, date: selectedDate)
    }
}
```

I set a breakline on the following line, and I can see that the value of `stop.date` is being updated:

```
    init(stop: Binding<TripStop>) {
        self._stop = stop
    }
```

However, `stop.date` on the following line continues to show the old date, despite the value being updated:

```
Text(stop.date?.formatDate(fromFormat: "YYYY-MM-dd", toFormat: "MMMM dd, YYYY") ?? "No date set")
```

I can't understand why this view isn't being updated, when in fact the binding value has been updated.

Here is what `TripStop` looks like:

```
struct TripStop: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let tripId: Int
    var date: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case tripId = "trip_id"
        case date = "date"
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you pass into the `init`? Please show a [mcve].

Comment: I suspect that you are still struggling to use `optional bindings`,  eg 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78143849/call-function-from-binding-returning-error
but do not want to take my advice here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78137370/cant-pass-object-as-binding-to-child-view-from-within-a-loop
Note, you should be using `.fullScreenCover(item:...)`